# Is there any way to put soft asserts in Espresso tests?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need my tests to run, if a certain condition fails (product search in this case, which often times out) it is retried and notifies for the error.  I can write custom check for this but then it will be specific to this case. I need it for handling multiple similar conditions.